# Twitter API: How to Get the Topic of Tweets?

Tags: python, json, twitter

I am trying to pull the Category/Topic of Tweets for a school project.
I am not seeing it as one of the keys in public_tweets (below), was wondering if it was located within a variable somewhere else? Thanks!

[image]

Example of a Twitter Topic/Category (would like to pull the “Lebron James” label):
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Topics are known as “context annotations” in the Twitter API, and are only available in v2. The Tweet data you have here is from v1.1. You’ll need to update the way you are accessing the API and add parameters to get Tweet expansions and fields for context annotations.